# Creating HashTable: TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, hashtable

I'm trying to create a Hash Table with the following code but when I create an instance of it, I get a:

> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

I'm not too sure where I'm going wrong; the Type Errors seem to refer to when I use the function `hashfunction`, but I can't seem to see where the type error is.

```
class HashTable:

def __init__(self):
    self.size = 11
    self.slots = [None] * self.size
    self.data = [None] * self.size

def hashfunction(self, key, size):
    # key is already the hashed ID
    return key % size

def rehash(self, old_hash_value, size):
    return (old_hash_value + 1) % size

def put(self, key, data): 
    hashvalue = self.hashfunction(data, len(self.slots))
    if self.slots[hashvalue] == None:
        self.slots[hashvalue] = hashvalue
        self.data[hashvalue] = data
    else:
        if self.slots[hashvalue] == key:
            self.data[hashvalue] == data
        else:
            nextslot = self.rehash(hashvalue, len(self.slots))
            while self.slots[nextslot] != None and self.slots[nextslots] != key: 
                nextslot = self.rehash(nextslot, len(self.slots))
            if self.slots[nextslot] == None:
                self.slots[nextslot] = key
                self.data[nextslot] = data
            else:
                self.data[nextslot] = data

def get(self, key): 
    start = self.hash(key, len(self.size))
    if self.slots[start] == key:
        return self.data[start] == key
    else: # slots[start] != key
        new_start = self.rehash(key, len(self.size))
        # recursive: if slots[new_start] == key, then return result

def __getitem__(self,key):
    return self.get(key)

def __setitem__(self, key, data):
    return self.put(key, data)


# Instance of HashTable

H = HashTable()
H[54] = "cat"
print(H.data)
```

Comment: `hashfunction()` claims that "key is already the hashed ID", but you're actually calling it with the DATA (apparently a string), not the key.  I do not see any actual computation of a hash value in your code.

Comment: As @Jason notes, the error is in the line `self.hashfunction(data, len(self.slots))`. It looked like there might be other issues too (e.g. I don't think that the `get` method makes sense), but passing a string is causing the exception in question.